# Get data from phpMyAdmin database from bluehost hosted website

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mamp, bluehost

I have a Bluehost hosted website. I have MAMP but I don't know how to use it.

How do I connect my iOS app to that database so I can access it anywhere?

Comment: There is no such thing as phpMyAdmin database. [phpMyAdmin is a free software tool written in PHP, intended to handle the administration of MySQL over the Web](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php).  The RDBMS is called MySql. Now find a tutorial and work it through. Then come back with a specific question and the code you've tried and SO community will be happy to help you.

Comment: I already have an app that takes data from databases inside a local phpMyAdmin. But that is just a local phpMyAdmin. Now I want to reach the phpMyAdmin that is connected to my website with Bluehost.com and display data from it so that I can not only access the databases within phpMyAdmin but also have it connected with my website. Sorry, I believe I worded my question poorly

Answer (score 0):

bluehost has a remote database section in the cpanel, You can add whatever IP address you need to access that database and use a remote mysql connection. If your ip address will change you can add a class C range, otherwise you may need a different database hosting provider that allows for wildcard ip addresses to connect.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old question. However it still opens and I would like to see if I can provide the right answer.

### Configuration Settings:

Use the following configuration settings for connecting to your database

```
Host name = (use the server IP address)
Database name = (cpanelUsername_databaseName)
Database username = (cpanelUsername_databaseUsername)
Database password = (the password you entered for that database user)
MySQL Connection Port = 3306
```

For adding a connection string to your PHP code using these configuration settings, please check this code

---

### MySQL Connection Strings

Allowing a Remote Server to Access Your Database

Before connecting to MySQL from another computer, the connecting computer must be enabled as an Access Host.

1. Log into cPanel and click the Remote MySQL icon, under Databases.
2. Type in the connecting IP address, and click the Add Host button.

   - **Note:** You can find and add your IP address directly from this tool. Look for Your IP is: **123.123.12.123** **[Add]**. Clicking the **[Add]** link will input your IP into the field box below.
3. Click Add, and you should now be able to connect remotely to your database.

---

### Configure phpMyAdmin Connect to remote server

Edit config file called `config.inc.php` The config file is located in phpMyAdmin folder. There should be a line like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

Change `localhost` to your server's `IP address`.

---

> How do I connect my iOS app to that database so I can access it anywhere?

http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/